# Half of Custom skin isn't changing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Half of my custom skin doesn't change when I edit it and save and upload it and it's frustrating because I'm just trying to make that half black... Can anyone help me out?

[image: That's the skin]

[image: and this is what it supposed to look like]

[image: This is what it looks like in game]

[[image: Backside[4]]

I'm using 1.7.10, but it let me change my skin before but not now, so it's just weird.